# Which, if any, CFD methods would be best for predicting performance of a sailboat?

Tags: cfd, boundary-layer

I am interested in using a CFD simulator to calculate the performance potential of a sailboat. And not just a single boat, but of multiple boats of different configurations and hull shapes. If I know all of the measurements and want to run a multi-phase simulation of the force vector resulting from the wind passing over the sail and the force vector resulting from the water passing over the hull is a CFD going to be a viable solution here?

Let me expand the idea further: I'd like to find a balance between precision and render time. Given the possible sail trim positions for each wind angle and the heel/pitch angles of the boat, and the different boat classes I don't want each render to take a month to complete.

Comment: Most CFD, like Phoenics, can do this - if they can model the working of the human heart then model the smoke progression over a burning city then the scale is covered. What you do to help the calculation time is to add cells to give the precision in the areas that is important, not just a uniform fine grid.

Comment: @SolarMike but is rendering in a CFD always the best for each boat type? Or is it best to establish a baseline render and use interpolation for different boats? If I had to render force vectors for hundreds of different boat classes each with different sail trims for the 180 degrees through the wind?

Comment: You want a VPP - velocity prediction program. It is a set of models that include sail performance, hull aero and hydro, appendage performance, course and environment specifics, and sometimes crew performance. https://orc.org/organization/velocity-prediction-program-vpp

Comment: @PhilSweet VPP is exactly what I'm trying to replace. They're generalist in their approach and rely on older nautical formulas. Sport boats and foiling boats do not rate very well in with heavier displacement boats. Their rating systems are also closed so nobody knows how they're calculating. I know someone associated with one and he told me that JBoats, Melges, and others got sweetheart ratings. I want to do an open source effort with full transparency.

Comment: @bcardarella https://www.boatdesign.net/threads/prandtls-lifting-line-method-for-sails.67845/. Remmlinger has been rolling his own VPP for about 10 years now. There are also some Hydro/Aero guys with Americas Cup and Olympic gold  credentials there - Mikko, T Speer, Baeckmo, etc. Most VPPs aren't really closed if you've got a few hundred thousand to spend on a peek and some documentation. Some even give you an hour of training.  :[ I think MIT handles the ORC VPP under contract.

Comment: Sails I can't help you with. Planing or semiplaning hulls I can't help you with. But displacement hulls can be accurately modelled with Michlet, up to multiples of hull speed (no waves admittedly). https://www.boatdesign.net/threads/michlet-9-33-released.52865/

Comment: Michlet can't do heeled hulls or account for leeway or induced drag. The developer, Leo Lazuskas, was a long-time mentor on BoatDesign.net His implementation of Michlet's inegral is basically a zeroth order approximation of the full Green's integral expression. When you try to go beyond zeroth order, it looks like this - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225162120_Practical_mathematical_representation_of_the_flow_due_to_a_distribution_of_sources_on_a_steadily_advancing_ship_hull